# Modify columns, by iterating through a list of tibbles

Tags: r, loops, iteration, tibble

I have created 8 tibbles from CSV files. Each tibble has a common column, `person_id`. The values in `person_id` are integers and I would like them to be factors.

I'm using tidyverse

Import

```
drugs <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_drugs.csv"))
flowsheet_dirty <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_flowsheet_dirty.csv"))
measurements_clean <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_measurements_clean.csv"))
measurements_dirty <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_measurements_dirty.csv"))
procedures_cpt <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_procedures_cpt.csv"))
vent_dirty <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_vent_dirty.csv"))
visits <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/icu_sample_visits.csv"))
person <- as_tibble(read.csv("../raw_data/icu_covid_sample/sample_icu_person.csv"))
```

Create a list

```
data_list <- list(drugs = drugs, flowsheet_dirty = flowsheet_dirty, measurements_clean = measurements_clean, measurements_dirty = measurements_dirty, procedures_cpt = procedures_cpt, vent_dirty = vent_dirty, visits = visits, person = person)
```

Some output:

```
> summary(data_list)
                   Length Class  Mode
drugs              12     tbl_df list
flowsheet_dirty    38     tbl_df list
measurements_clean 13     tbl_df list
measurements_dirty 13     tbl_df list
procedures_cpt      4     tbl_df list
vent_dirty         12     tbl_df list
visits             18     tbl_df list
person             39     tbl_df list
```

Every tibble in the list has a column "person_id"

ex. drugs$person_id, visits$person_id, etc.

```
> seq_along(data_list)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

I would like to iterate with a for loop to convert every person_id column into factor data, instead of integer. More generally, I want to know how to apply functions to a group of tibbles by having them in a list.

```
for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
  data_list[i]$person_id <- as.factor(data_list[i]$person_id)
}
```

Error output:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

One test (has to be done prior to loop error)

```
data_list$drugs$person_id <- as.factor(data_list$drugs$person_id)

> is.factor(data_list$drugs$person_id)
[1] TRUE
> is.factor(data_list$visit$person_id)
[1] FALSE
```

This also doesn't work:

```
for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
  data_list[[i]]$person_id <- as.factor(data_list[[i]]$person_id)
}
```

Error:

```
Unknown or uninitialised column: `person_id`.Error: Assigned data `as.factor(data_list[[i]]$person_id)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 6 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_error()
<error/tibble_error_assign_incompatible_size>
Assigned data `as.factor(data_list[[i]]$person_id)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 6 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
 1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, "person_id", value = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"))
 2. tibble:::`$<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, "person_id", value = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"))
 3. tibble:::tbl_subassign(...)
 4. tibble:::vectbl_recycle_rhs(...)
 5. base::tryCatch(...)
 6. base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7. base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8. value[[3L]](cond)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.

> rlang::last_trace()
<error/tibble_error_assign_incompatible_size>
Assigned data `as.factor(data_list[[i]]$person_id)` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 6 rows.
x Assigned data has 0 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Backtrace:
    x
 1. +-base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, "person_id", value = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"))
 2. \-tibble:::`$<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, "person_id", value = structure(integer(0), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"))
 3.   \-tibble:::tbl_subassign(...)
 4.     \-tibble:::vectbl_recycle_rhs(...)
 5.       \-base::tryCatch(...)
 6.         \-base:::tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 7.           \-base:::tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8.             \-value[[3L]](cond)
>
```

So I know that with 8 commands I can convert the person_id columns to integers, but I am having trouble doing it in a loop. Additionally, maybe mutate() could help me, however I would like to be facile with iterations. Additionally, I am not sure that my data_list should be a list. Perhaps it should be a vector or something else. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible to update with `dput` of a head of single list element ie. `dput(droplevels(head(data_list[[1]])))`

Answer (score 1):

Here, we need to do the extraction with `[[` instead of `[` because `[` returns a `list` of length 1 and it is not extracting the data

```
for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
   data_list[[i]][["person_id"]] <- as.factor(data_list[[i]][["person_id"]])
  }
```

Based on the error showed, there may be datasets that doesn't have the 'person_id'.  In that case, we can have a check for the 'person_id' and if it is present, then do the following

```
for (i in seq_along(data_list)) {
   i1 <-  'person_id' %in% names(data_list[[i]])
   if(i1) {
    data_list[[i]]$person_id <- as.factor(data_list[[i]]$person_id)  
    }
}
```

---

As a reproducible example

```
lst1 <- list(as_tibble(head(mtcars)) %>% 
            mutate(person_id = 1:6), 
            as_tibble(head(iris)) %>%
               mutate(person_id = 1:6))
for(i in seq_along(lst1))  lst1[[i]]$person_id <- as.factor(lst1[[i]]$person_id)
is.factor(lst1[[1]]$person_id)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or this can be done with `lapply`

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, transform, person_id = as.factor(person_id))
```

---

Or another option is `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data_list <- map(data_list, ~ .x %>% 
                      person_id = factor(person_id))
```

Comment: I edited my question to include the [[ ]] recommendation you gave, that gives an error too. I had tried that once I think. I will look over all of these options carefully and respond with results. ty.

Comment: @BryanRoller can you try with the second and third method

Comment: This is elegant, however it doesn't quite work:

```
data_list <- lapply(data_list, transform, person_id = as.factor(person_id))

Error in is.factor(x) : object 'person_id' not found
```

The person_id column is nested one level down. It is 
```
data_list$drugs$person_id or data_list$visits$person_id
```
How do I run the command in one line on all tibbles in the datalist? with out specifying each tibble specifically?

Comment: @BryanRoller the error shows that you don't have a column named `person_id`

Comment: I do have a column person_id, however it is not in data_list. data_list has 8 categories, drugs, person, visits, measurements_clean, etc. Each of these categories has a person_id column that I want to change. person_id is nested one level down.

Comment: @BryanRoller as I understand from the structure.  it is a `list` of tibbles.  If that is the case, it sshould have worked e.g. `lst1 <- list(tibble(person_id = 1:5, col2 = 1:5), tibble(person_id = 6:10, col2 = 6:10))`

Comment: @BryanRoller Can you update your post with `str(data_list)`

Comment: @BryanRoller can you change the line to `data_list[[i]][["person_id"]] <- as.factor(data_list[[i]][["person_id"]])`

Comment: @BryanRoller it is a bit strange as I couldn't reproduce that error with the list I created (updated)